# What does this condition check pass in cairo-lang?

Tags: cairo-lang

I am looking at the paradigm ctf 2022 [Cairo auction problem](https://github.com/paradigmxyz/paradigm-ctf-2022/blob/main/cairo-auction/public/contracts/auction.cairo#L185-L190). The vulnerability lies in the 5 quoted lines. Here it is checking whether amount is less or equal to unlocked_balance. Both variables are uint256.

```
let (current_balance) = _balances.read(account=caller)
let (locked_balance) = _lockedBalancesOf.read(account=caller)
let (unlocked_balance) = uint256_sub(current_balance, locked_balance)
let (enough_balance) = uint256_le(amount, unlocked_balance)

assert enough_balance = 1
```

The solution sends [`amount = { low: 2**128+1, high: 0 }`](https://github.com/paradigmxyz/paradigm-ctf-2022/blob/main/cairo-auction/private/solve.py#L11) and passes the check with `unlocked_balance = 0`.

My question is how does this work, that `uint256_le({ low: 2**128+1, high: 0 }, 0) == 1` ? Is this a known vulnerability in cairo-lang?

Comment: It seems this [link](https://amanusk.medium.com/paradigm-ctf-cairo-solutions-3a4b31210918) discusses the same problem (under the Challenge #3 header)